# Websocket works well on Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, amazon-web-services, websocket

i've setted up a websocket server in aws ec2, with php sockets, using my dns as the ws url, like:

var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://ec2-177-71-x-x.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:60997');

Here is the Request in firefox console:

```
Host: ec2-177-71-x-x.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:60997
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Key: csxgGFmTuJYxgvfsbgKtyA==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

And the Response:

```
Connection: "Upgrade"
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "AmwLLFdVkE9buCccH1oggz4FNJM="
Upgrade: "websocket"
WebSocket-Location: "ws://ec2-177-71-x-x.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:60997"
WebSocket-Origin: "ec2-177-71-x-x.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Seems like Google Chrome can not reach the websocket server, i've tryed to put the url in http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, but only firefox connects.

i guess the problem could be the handshake, here is the function i'm using

```
//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    var_dump($receved_header);
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];

    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    var_dump(socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade)));
}
```

Additional Info: I've setted this same websocket in both local, and testing server, wich is a Centos 6.0 machine with php 5.4+, and worked well in both chrome and firefox.
The version of php in production server, where the issue is occurring is: PHP 5.3.27

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved: Squid does not support protocol upgrade websocket connection proxy, and firefox attempt to do a protocol connection if websocket fails